# Why is matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation producing a blank ouput in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, matplotlib-animation

I'm learning Python's matplotlib FuncAnimation method but can't get a basic Bayesian conjugates animation to run. When I run this, I just get a blank output in my Jupyter notebook. I also get same result using Google Colab. How do I get animation to run and show?

Note, I could get official animation tutorial scripts to run... It's just an issue with the code below.

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gamma, poisson

np.random.seed(0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [])

def animate(i):
    if i == 0:
        x = np.linspace(0, 30, 1000)
        alpha = 2
        beta = 1
        y = gamma.pdf(x, a=alpha, scale=beta)
        line.set_data(x, y)
        return line,
    else:
        sample = poisson.rvs(4)
        alpha += sample
        beta += 1
        y = gamma.pdf(x, a=alpha, scale=beta)
        line.set_data(x, y)
        return line,
    
%matplotlib notebook
%matplotlib notebook

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=2, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I create animations in jupyterlab, I specify the following library, which seems to use html5's video function to draw.

```
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import HTML
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gamma, poisson

np.random.seed(0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [])

def animate(i):
    if i == 0:
        x = np.linspace(0, 30, 1000)
        alpha = 2
        beta = 1
        y = gamma.pdf(x, a=alpha, scale=beta)
        line.set_data(x, y)
        return line,
    else:
        x = np.linspace(0, 30, 1000)
        alpha = 2
        beta = 1
        sample = poisson.rvs(4)
        alpha += sample
        beta += 1
        y = gamma.pdf(x, a=alpha, scale=beta)
        line.set_data(x, y)
        return line,

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=2, blit=True)
# plt.show()

plt.close()
HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

[image]

Comment: I think what gets it to work is that `plt.close()` call